# SQL Query is giving me a Non-Boolean expression error

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting an error that reads An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '20'. 20 is the SelectedPort value in the Query String I think there is something wrong in this Query.

```
string tablename = cboNetGuid.SelectedItem.ToString();

SqlConnection sqlConnectionCmdString = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\database\ClientRegit.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

//Properly Defines the string for naming the table according to the systems naming scheme
string Command = "SELECT Client_Groups, Company, Occupation, ClientID FROM [" + tablename + "] WHERE Port = [" + SelectedPort + "]";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, sqlConnectionCmdString);

// will be retrieved - reading methods
// sqlComgroup.Parameters["@Network"].Value = cboNetGuid.SelectedItem.ToString();

sqlConnectionCmdString.Open(); // open database connection

// create database reader to read information from database
SqlDataReader objReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

// retrieve information from database
while (objReader.Read())
{

  cboClientGroup.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objReader["Client_Groups"]));

  cboOccupation.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objReader["Occupation"]));

  cboCompany.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objReader["Company"]));

  cboClientID.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(objReader["ClientID"]));
}

objReader.Close();
sqlConnectionCmdString.Close();
```

Comment: it is nice if you format you code so it is readable.

Answer (score 3):

You're not comparing `SelectedPort` to anything in your SQL.
The SQL server expects a condition like:

```
WHERE SelectedPort = Something
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `WHERE SelectedPort = Something`. It's T-SQL, not C#

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @PoweredByOrange and thanks for the edit DanielGimenez.

Comment: Thanks guys that worked I forgot to include the actual table column I was just passing the Value in the WHERE Clause

Comment: Hi! Did my answer help you? I would appreciate if you could accept the answer if it did. Thank you!